# How can I get a wireshark Lua dissector protocol preferences to save and persist when I close wireshark?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

So I have written what I can only refer to as an Awesome dissector. It doesn't do much, yet it boosts my work efficiency greatly.

My only problem is that I exposed a few preferences, and they won't stick through wireshark close/start.

I.E. :

Prerequisite : Lua script must be in plugins dir...

1. Open wireshark, Edit > Preferences > Protocol > http.queryparameters...
2. Set Param1 Value to "aaa", click OK. (It will affect dissection properly.)
3. Close wireshark, Start again, the value is again something else.

My dissector :

```
-- Written by Eitam Doodai
-- trivial postdissector example
-- declare some Fields to be read
full_uri_from_request = Field.new("http.request.full_uri")

-- declare our (pseudo) protocol
http_query_params_proto = Proto("http.query_parameters","HTTP Query Parameters Postdissector")

-- create the fields for our "protocol"
query_param1 = ProtoField.string("http.query_parameters.param1","PARAM1")
query_param2 = ProtoField.string("http.query_parameters.param2","PARAM2")
query_param3 = ProtoField.string("http.query_parameters.param3","PARAM3")

-- add the field to the protocol
http_query_params_proto.fields = {query_param1}
http_query_params_proto.fields = {query_param2}
http_query_params_proto.fields = {query_param3}

-- Add prefs
local p1 = http_query_params_proto.prefs
p1.value1 = Pref.string ("Param1 Value", "123", "Param key to extract")
p1.value2 = Pref.string ("Param2 Value", "456", "Param key to extract")
p1.value3 = Pref.string ("Param3 Value", "789", "Param key to extract")

-- create a function to "postdissect" each frame
function http_query_params_proto.dissector(buffer,pinfo,tree)
        -- obtain the current values the protocol fields
        local full_uri_value = full_uri_from_request()
        if full_uri_value then
                local value = tostring(full_uri_value)
                local subtree = tree:add(http_query_params_proto,"Query Param1")
                local subtree = tree:add(http_query_params_proto,"Query Param2")
                local subtree = tree:add(http_query_params_proto,"Query Param3")
                _, _, query_param1_str = string.find(value,p1.value1 .. "=([^&]+)")
                _, _, query_param2_str = string.find(value,p1.value2 .. "=([^&]+)")
                _, _, query_param3_str = string.find(value,p1.value3 .. "=([^&]+)")
                if query_param1_str then
                        subtree:add(query_param1,query_param1_str)
                end

                if query_param2_str then
                        subtree:add(query_param2,query_param2_str)
                end
                if query_param3_str then
                        subtree:add(query_param3,query_param3_str)
                end
        end
end

-- register our protocol as a postdissector
register_postdissector(http_query_params_proto)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a console open and start wireshark from the command line, after you change one of your `http.query_parameters.param` settings, save it and close wireshark, and restart it, you'll see something like:

```
...preferences line 1829: No such preference "http.query_parameters.value2" (applying your preferences once should remove this warning)
```

And that's a problem: wireshark prints that out for preferences it finds in the saved preference file that it doesn't understand/know-about.

Edit: do NOT open a bug about this. The problem is you used a Protocol name that already exists with preferences: "`http`".  In other words, since you're basically naming the preferences `http.query...`, wireshark thinks it should belong to the `http` protocol module, but the *real* `http` module doesn't know anything about it, so wireshark prints that error the next time it tries reading from the preferences file.

Long story short: change the name of your Proto and fields and so on, to not collide with a real protocol name.

Comment: Precious, Even after asking the question I kept trying and was about to give up - You really helped me. (I know this comment is useless on the SO level, but as a human I'm inclined.)